# AFNetworking AFJSONRequestOperation Caching & API Request Limiting

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am pulling data from an api using the code below. I would like to utilize caching or something to only request the information once every 3 hours. What is my best option here for this?

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

    success([NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[JSON objectForKey:@"daily"] objectForKey:@"data"]]);

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){

    failure(error);

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach (if you can) is to set max-age header on the response request and let NSURLCache handle all the logic.

See how to set max-age and other headers here: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL

And to enable cache on you app, just place this on the app delegate didFinishLoading:

```
//Here we declare a shared NSURLCache with 2mb of memory and 100mb of disk space
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:2 * 1024 * 1024
                                          diskCapacity:100 * 1024 * 1024
                                          diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Comment: Once I do that, do I need to change the way my information is retrieved after the request takes place?

Comment: @TerryG, no, not at all, that's the beauty of it, you don't have to change a thing, all still the same except that requests now complies with the caching policy specified by the server on the response

Comment: This is the best answer.  If you can't set the cache-control headers properly, https://github.com/steipete/SDURLCache will allow you to override cacheing logic on the client side.  It's always better to do it server-side though.